# Virtual network warns about address overlap with itself

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

Azure warns about the address spaces of one virtual network overlapping with the address space of another (such networks cannot be peered). This makes sense.

However, I am noticing that Azure *also* warns me about the address space of a virtual network overlapping with *itself*:

[image]

> Address space 10.2.0.0/16 overlaps with address space 10.2.0.0/16 of virtual network 'poboy_vnet'. [...]

There is only one `poboy_vnet` in my subscription.

Is this a bug?

P.S. Not sure but it is possible this only occurs with vnets that are peered with some other vnet.

Edit: Since @Imran mentioned address space overlap between different subnets of `poboy_vnet` as a possible reason, here is the subnet configuration. As far as I can tell there is no address space overlap:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug and has been resolved. You can navigate to https://ms.portal.azure.com/?feature.canmodifystamps=true&Microsoft_Azure_Network=flight4

This URL wont perm fix the issue but, if you need to peer a vnet, you can login with that URL temporarily to peer the vnets or manage the vnets until the fix is globally deployed, sometime next week.

Comment: Great, happy to see this being followed up on!

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same issue since yesterday. I agree that this warning feels like a bug. None of the address ranges in my vNets are overlapping and even the subnets are correct and non-overlapping.

Seems like some bug since it started from yesterday and not before that.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment I got the results successfully like below:***

The reason you are seeing this warning is because of virtual network's address spaces overlap those to another virtual network same address space is defined multiple times within the same virtual network. This may occur if several subnets are sharing the same address space within a single virtual network.

Each virtual network has a unique address space. If you define the same address space for multiple subnets within a virtual network you will receive a warning that the address space overlaps with itself.

To resolve this issue, Check the below workarounds:

If your Address space is overlapping try to remove the subnet like below:

[image]

In Address space, I have added a new address space and created a subnet with that address space like below:

[image]

[image]

To peer vnet create another virtual network with default subnet and peering with khan-vnet successfully like below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Imran, am I understanding correctly that the reason for the warning may be that there is overlap between the address space of different subnets of my vnet? I just added the subnet configuration to the post - as far as I can tell none of the subnets overlap.

Comment: expected if you have a virtual machine or any other services is manually assigned an IP address that falls within the address space of the virtual network check none of the resources are using IP addresses that overlap with the virtual network's address space

Comment: Thanks Imran, I checked that (a) all devices connected to the `poboy_vnet` have IP addresses in the range specified by the subnet, and (b) devices connected to peered networks seem to have IP addresses outside this range. The warning still feels like a bug

Answer (score 0):

Noticed the same for newly added address space. Then checked for existing Virtual Networks and found that warning is displayed for last address space in every Virtual Network. Seems to be bug.